# Implement MLP in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

There are many resources online about how to implement MLP in tensorflow, and most of the samples do work :) But I am interested in a particular one, that I learned from https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning. In which, it uses a *cost* function defined as follow:

$
J(\theta) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \left[ -y_k^{(i)} \log((h_\theta(x^{(i)}))_k - (1 - y_k^{(i)}) \log(1 - (h_\theta(x^{(i)}))_k \right]
$

$h_\theta$ is the *sigmoid* function.

And there's my implementation:

```
# one hidden layer MLP

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 512]))
h1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W_h1))

W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512, 10]))
y_ = tf.matmul(h1, W_out)

# cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_, y)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(- y * tf.log(y_) - (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - y_), 1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# train
with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in range(10000):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        s.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            print('step {0}, training accuracy {1}'.format(i, train_accuracy))
```

I think the definition for the layers are correct, but the problem is in the *cross_entropy*. If I use the first one, *the one got commented out*, the model converges quickly; **but if I use the 2nd one, which I think/hope is the translation of the previous equation, the model won't converge.**

Comment: There are several mistakes stemming from your application of the binary logistic regression model to the [multinomial case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) (remember that MNIST has ten classes). Please follow the [tensorflow MNIST guide for beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html).

Comment: @Emre, it would be very appreciate if you can point out where I got wrong. Thanks~

Comment: Your loss function and its arguments are both wrong. I don't think it would work as is even if it were binary; the argument of the loss function is not normalized. Please follow the links.

Comment: I implemented the model using *numpy* and *scipy* and it works. When I try to print the `y_` during the training loop, the elements are all **nan**. I think there's some arithmetic error happened in tensorflow, but I could not figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I don't have tensorflow to try it, but I think you forgot to apply the sigmoid function on y_. Try y_ = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h1, W_out)) instead of y_ = tf.matmul(h1, W_out).

Comment: @stmax, thanks, but I tried that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made three mistakes:

1. You omitted the offset terms before the nonlinear transformations (variables b_1 and b_out). This increases the representative power of the neural network.
2. You omitted the softmax transformation at the top layer. This makes the output a probability distributions, so you can calculate the cross-entropy, which is the usual cost function for classification.
3. You used the binary form of the cross-entropy when you should have used the multi-class form.

When I run this I get accuracies over 90%:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/tmp/MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 512]))
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512]))
h1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W_h1) + b_1)

W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512, 10]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))
y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h1, W_out) + b_out)

# cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_, y)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(- y * tf.log(y_), 1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# train
with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in range(10000):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        s.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        if i % 1000 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            print('step {0}, training accuracy {1}'.format(i, train_accuracy))
```

Comment: For sure your implementation is correct. But I wanted to follow the idea from the course strictly. I omitted `bias` terms for I am lazy :) I think the steps to compute `softmax` and `cross entropy` is where I did wrong.

Comment: You are right; the bias is "optional", but the softmax is essential.

Comment: A bit late, but I believe `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` takes the logits (that is the previous layer without any activation), not the softmax as an input. So: `tf.nn. sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(tf.matmul(h1, W_out) + b_out)` would be better. For single label classification (such as NIST written digits) one would use `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. Would love to hear if I got it wrong.